Same query, same data - but much longer execution time and more reads in another server
I have a query that includes an inner join between 2 tables.
When I use SET STATISTICS to get some information, I can see that the order of execution and reads is much different from one server to another. The data is identical:
Server 1 (fast, instant execution time):
Table 'A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1001
Table 'B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 183

Server 2 (slow, 20+ seconds):
Table 'B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 432112
Table 'A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2643

For the slow executing server, the order is different and so are the number of reads.
The query's structure is this:
SELECT *
FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.employee_id = B.employee_id
                       AND A.year = B.year
                       AND A.month = B.month
WHERE A.year = 2024
  AND A.month = 10

I've also noticed that when I comment the AND A.month = 10, the order of the execution changes in the slow server like the fast one and the execution time is instant. However still with more reads:
Server 2 (without 'AND A.month = 10'):
Table 'A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2807
Table 'B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 191

How can I keep debugging it to try to make it run as fast as in the first server?

have you updated your statistics ?  sounds like parameter sniffing (which stats may or may not fix)

How can I check if it's updated? I am quite new to sql server

I install this to update stats: https://github.com/yochananrachamim/AzureSQL/blob/master/AzureSQLMaintenance.txt

thank you, and what exactly does it do? why it may cause the change in this execution plan and read count? It's so much higher in the slow server. I'm just curious as to what may be the cause for this big difference

you need to post the plans for both querys. to update stats, run : exec [dbo].[AzureSQLMaintenance] 'statistics', 'smart';

While I was here, one of the team mates copied the entire data from both tables to new tables and it fixed itself. You think it can provide more information as to what it might've been? Because right now I can't run the above query (no permissions)

see my first comment .... type parameter sniffing in a search engine  and read https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Oh! So it might still be it. I will read now. One more question please since I haven't read yet - If the issue with my query was indeed parameter sniffing, could the slow query problem return to this server after a while? Or the clean data copy solved that? Or, it means there's something in the query that can stuck it overtime? Thank you!

if it's param sniffing, the problem could re-occur.

Thank you. I will read it now. Also I did change the query itself overtime via the code (I'm building this query using an ORM, not raw SQL)

Have you tries to rebuild the indexes? I have worked on systems that needed that on occation.

@W_O_L_F I couldn't perform operations on this table as I did not have permissions (I only write the code). However if it happens again I will try to tell them to do that
